# PHP - Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

How do I replace a 4 digit string with a given string using PHP

```
$original_string = "test343443test34demo55555"
$replace_string = "TEST"
```

**output**

```
$output = testTESTtest34demoTEST
```

How do I do this using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = preg_replace('/\d{5,}/', $replace_string, $original_string);
```

This really is quite basic though; so you should look into reading PHP's documentation before asking further questions like this. Remember, [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128553#128553) and programming requires effort on your part.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace("@\\d{5,}@", "TEST", "test343443test34demo55555");
//                       ^-------- note: no digits after comma
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/(\d){5,}/","TEST",$original_string);
```